# How to evenly distribute work for an all-pairs test of n objects over n threads?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing

A typical single-threaded loop over all possible (unordered) pairs from a set of `n` objects looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        ProcessPair(i, j);
```

Now say you have `n` threads at your disposal. The obvious way to implement the above in parallel is something like:

```
for (int j = threadIndex + 1; j < n; j++)
    ProcessPair(threadIndex, j);
```

But this doesn't distribute the work evenly across threads. The first thread will process `n-1` pairs while the last one will process none.

Is there a simple way to have the set of `n(n-1)/2` pairs partitioned such that each thread processes the same number of pairs (±1) and can determine which ones it is supposed to process based only on its `threadIndex` and `n`?

This interesting problem came up as I was playing with physics on the GPU and started to implement a brute force all-pairs collision detection (I know, I should use a broad-phase algorithm). I'm thinking that the [combinatorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) might be key to this, but I can't quite fit all the pieces together.

Comment: What about using a separate counter variable and calling `ProcessPair(dispatchCounter % numberOfThreads, i, j)`?

Comment: @zneak I'm not sure I get how this is helpful? The goal is to have `ProcessPair(i,j)` called once for every possible set `{i,j}`, where `i≠j`.

Comment: One general approach would be to find a bijection between sets `{i,j}` and the number range `[1..n(n-1)/2]`

Comment: One "obvious" bijection is `f(i,j) = j - i - 1 + n(n-1)/2 - (n-i)(n-i-1)/2` (just numbering the cells in a matrix from top to bottom, left to right) :P it's a bit awkward to invert unfortunately, not nearly as elegant as Ehsan's solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played around a bit with it and I've got a solution that seems to be correct. I don't have a proof for it working or for it being balanced, but it logically makes sense as far as I can tell.

In words:
If you're at an even index, check against all even indices smaller than you and all odd indices bigger than you. If you're at an odd index, check against all odd indices smaller than you and all even indices bigger than you.

It's fairly easy to see that each thread will compare against at most N/2 other threads since we are going over the whole list in steps of 2.

Comment: I've experimentally confirmed it to work. Very cool algorithm!

Comment: Brilliant. I have also confirmed it, via a pictorial proof. All pairs are processed exactly once, and when N is even half the threads process N/2 pairs and the other half process N/2-1 pairs.